# post form variable to php return result and place in div

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to submit a form post to a php page (which has dummy vars) then return the results and display them in the 'userinfo' div on the same page. I suspect I need to post the information to the same page or use Ajax but unsure on how to achieve this.

A few hours of trawling the web hasn't provided any decent examples of what I am trying to do.

any help appreciated:

Anyway here is the code:

```
        <form name="Find User" id="userform" class="invoform" method="post" action="includes/find.php" />
            <div id ="userdiv">
                <p>Name (Lastname, firstname):</p></label><input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="inputfield" />
                <input type="submit" name="find" id="find" class="passwordsubmit" value="find" />
            </div>
        </form>
        <div id="userinfo"><b>info will be listed here.</b></div>
```

php dummy vars:

```
<?php

$user=$_POST['username'];
$username="username";
$gg_groups="gg_usergroups";
$enabled="True";

$result = array(
    'username' => $username,
    'user' => $user,
    'usergroups' => $gg_groups,
    'enabled'=> $enabled
);

echo json_encode($result);

?>
```

Comment: [Seriously, few hours?](http://www.google.com/search?q=send+form+jquery+ajax) I'm sorry it's not topic related, it just seem you haven't done any serious research.

Comment: Point taken, if I knew what I was looking for I would. when you google examples of post to php, return value to div it doesnt exactly produce any good examples. also, you are only seeing a simplified code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what your trying to do? Submitting a form to the same page is easy, just leave the action attribute blank like this:

```
<form name="Find User" id="userform" class="invoform" method="post" action="">
```

Then add this to the php, to check if the forms been sent:

```
if(isset($_POST['find'])){
    //Do whatever you want with the form here
}
```

EDIT AFTER COMMENT:
Well its hard to give you an exact code without all the code, but sticking with just php, why not send the form to the page you want it to be displayed on, include the php file which processes the results then write an echo statement to output the result? something like this:

```
    <form name="Find User" id="userform" class="invoform" method="post" action="">
        <div id ="userdiv">
            <p>Name (Lastname, firstname):</p></label><input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="inputfield" />
            <input type="submit" name="find" id="find" class="passwordsubmit" value="find" />
        </div>
    </form>
    <div id="userinfo">
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['find'])){
        include('dummyvars.php');
        echo"Username = ". $username . "<br> User = ". $user ."<br> Usergroups = ". $gg_groups ."<br> Enabled = ". $enabled;
    }
    ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: I'm trying to post the form results to a php page which will disply the results in the 'uservars' div.

Comment: Check my edit, is that what your looking for?

Comment: LOL! :D So simple and exactly what I am looking for. Odd, I could do that but it did not even cross my mind.

Comment: The simple ways normally the best way! Glad i could help!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `jQuery.ajax()`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "some.php",
    data: {$("#username").val();}
    success: function(data) {
        $("#userval").text(data.username);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery library and this javascript code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#find').click(function(){
        var form = $(this).closest('form');

        $.post(form.attr('action'), form.serialize(), function (data){
            var c;
            $.each(data, function(i, e){
                c += i + ':' + e;
            });
            $('#userinfo').html(c);
        }, 'json');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery and bind event to submit action.

```
 $(function (){

 $("#userform").submit(function (){
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "some.php",
    data: {username : $("#username").val()}
    success: function(data) {
       $("#userinfo b").html(data.username);
    }
  });

  });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

$("#find").click(function(){
    var username  = $("#username").val();
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'includes/find.php',
        data: 'username='+username,
        success: function( data ) {
        //in data you result will be available...show here

        },

error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    alert(status);
    },
dataType: 'text'

});
    });

});



</script>

<form name="Find User" id="userform" class="invoform" method="post" />

<div id ="userdiv">
  <p>Name (Lastname, firstname):</p>
  </label>
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="inputfield" />
  <input type="button" name="find" id="find" class="passwordsubmit" value="find" />
</div>
</form>
<div id="userinfo"><b>info will be listed here.</b></div>
```